# Implicit declaration of function ‘swapcontext’ on Mac OS

Tags: c, multithreading, macos

I just upload my proj to github:
https://github.com/gitlwh/whyisthis/tree/master

You can clone it and run on your Mac. It is convenient.
When I run `make` in the root folder, it shows:

```
uthread.c:21:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘swapcontext’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   swapcontext(&currentThread->context,&scheduler_context);
   ^
uthread.c: In function ‘main_manager’:
uthread.c:31:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘setcontext’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  setcontext(&mainThread->context);
  ^
uthread.c: In function ‘initialer’:
uthread.c:72:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getcontext’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     getcontext(&initThread->context);
     ^
uthread.c: In function ‘THREAD_INIT’:
uthread.c:112:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘makecontext’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   makecontext(&mainThread->context, (void(*)(void)) main_manager, 0, NULL, NULL);
   ^
```

I have looked up much material online and replaced ucontext.h with sys/ucontext.h.  I really don't know why is this.

Update:
If I change to ucontext.h, it would show:

```
uthread.c: In function ‘signal_handler’:
uthread.c:21:3: warning: ‘swapcontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   swapcontext(&currentThread->context,&scheduler_context);
   ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:40:6: note: declared here
 int  swapcontext(ucontext_t * __restrict, const ucontext_t * __restrict) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c: In function ‘main_manager’:
uthread.c:31:2: warning: ‘setcontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  setcontext(&mainThread->context);
  ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:39:6: note: declared here
 int  setcontext(const ucontext_t *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c:32:2: warning: ‘setcontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  setcontext(&scheduler_context);
  ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:39:6: note: declared here
 int  setcontext(const ucontext_t *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c: In function ‘thread_manager’:
uthread.c:43:2: warning: ‘setcontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  setcontext(&scheduler_context);
  ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:39:6: note: declared here
 int  setcontext(const ucontext_t *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c: In function ‘scheduler’:
uthread.c:55:9: warning: ‘swapcontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         swapcontext(&scheduler_context,&currentThread->context);
         ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:40:6: note: declared here
 int  swapcontext(ucontext_t * __restrict, const ucontext_t * __restrict) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c: In function ‘initialer’:
uthread.c:72:5: warning: ‘getcontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     getcontext(&initThread->context);
     ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:37:6: note: declared here
 int  getcontext(ucontext_t *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c: In function ‘THREAD_INIT’:
uthread.c:112:3: warning: ‘makecontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   makecontext(&mainThread->context, (void(*)(void)) main_manager, 0, NULL, NULL);
   ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:38:6: note: declared here
 void makecontext(ucontext_t *, void (*)(), int, ...) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c: In function ‘THREAD_CREATE’:
uthread.c:138:3: warning: ‘makecontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   makecontext(&newThread->context, (void(*)(void)) thread_manager, 2, func, arg);
   ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:38:6: note: declared here
 void makecontext(ucontext_t *, void (*)(), int, ...) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c:143:3: warning: ‘getcontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   getcontext(&mainThread->context);
   ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:37:6: note: declared here
 int  getcontext(ucontext_t *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c:157:3: warning: ‘getcontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   getcontext(&newThread->context);
   ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:37:6: note: declared here
 int  getcontext(ucontext_t *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c:169:3: warning: ‘makecontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   makecontext(&newThread->context, (void(*)(void)) thread_manager, 2, func, arg);
   ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:38:6: note: declared here
 void makecontext(ucontext_t *, void (*)(), int, ...) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c:172:3: warning: ‘swapcontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   swapcontext(&currentThread->context,&scheduler_context);
   ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:40:6: note: declared here
 int  swapcontext(ucontext_t * __restrict, const ucontext_t * __restrict) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c: In function ‘THREAD_EXIT’:
uthread.c:209:2: warning: ‘setcontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  setcontext(&scheduler_context);
  ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:39:6: note: declared here
 int  setcontext(const ucontext_t *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c: In function ‘THREAD_YIELD’:
uthread.c:217:5: warning: ‘getcontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     getcontext(&currentThread->context);
     ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:37:6: note: declared here
 int  getcontext(ucontext_t *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
uthread.c:221:9: warning: ‘setcontext’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         setcontext(&scheduler_context);
         ^
In file included from uthread.h:8:0,
                 from uthread.c:1:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:39:6: note: declared here
 int  setcontext(const ucontext_t *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_5, __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_2_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
      ^
```

Comment: "replaced ucontext.h with sys/ucontext.h". Why did you do that? What was the behaviour before you did that? The [swapcontext man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/swapcontext) says to include `<ucontext.h>`.

Comment: On MAC OS, you should replace ucontext.h with sys/ucontext.h ? Also, it seems you need to do same thing with many packages. Try to `make` my proj, it is convenient.

Answer (score 0):

> On MAC OS, you should replace `ucontext.h` with `sys/ucontext.h`? Also, it seems you need to do same thing with many packages.

No; you should not replace `<ucontext.h>` with `<sys/ucontext.h>`; the macOS manual is quite clear that you should use `#include <ucontext.h>` and going against that will lead to problems.

What compilation options are you using?

The header contains `#ifdef _XOPEN_SOURCE` and then defines the functions, but there's also an `#else` clause which says

```
#error The deprecated ucontext routines require _XOPEN_SOURCE to be defined
```

So, on macOS, it is preferred that you don't use the functions — but neither the header nor the manual page for `swapcontext()` says what the preferred alternative is (assuming there is an alternative), which is irritating.  If you do want to use the `ucontext` functions, you must ensure `_XOPEN_SOURCE` is defined when you compile.  You can do that directly on the command line, or via a header.  (I use my own header `posixver.h` for the task; you can find a copy of it in directory https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq.)

---

> Compiling with `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE` now gives warnings about the function being deprecated — what can I do about that?

The function is marked deprecated and you get warnings when you use it because it *is* deprecated — but the function is now declared. If you don't want the deprecation warning, add `-Wno-deprecated-declarations` to the compiler options. Or rewrite the code to use some other mechanism to manage whatever you're doing with `swapcontext()`.

Note that the compiler tells you which option triggered the warning so you can suppress it as shown with the `no-` prefix. You could also use `-Werror=deprecated-declarations` to force it to be an error rather than a warning. If the compiler doesn't include the name of a flag like that in the message, you probably can't suppress the warning or error.

Comment: Could you see my github link? Makefile is there. I update my question, I have defined `_XOPEN_SOURCE`.